# Combine two mysql query into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, union

What is the proper syntax to combine these two queries?

```
SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable WHERE clicks > 199 ORDER BY clicks ASC LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 1
```

I tried:

```
SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable WHERE clicks > 199 ORDER BY clicks ASC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 1;
```

but I get "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY".

**EDIT**
Additionally, I want the result to be returned in a single row. So that I can access the value in php eg

```
$row['nextclick'] and $row['topclick']
```

From Simon's suggestion, I should not use UNION because I want to return a single row of data

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't `ORDER BY` in your first `SELECT` and then `UNION` it.

**Edit**
You can however

> apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:

as in the [MySQL UNION documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html)

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

Which then makes your SQL

```
(SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable WHERE clicks > 199 ORDER BY clicks ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 1);
```

**Edit 2**
To return in an `array`

```
SELECT (SELECT clicks 
        FROM clicksTable 
        WHERE clicks > 199 
        ORDER BY clicks ASC 
        LIMIT 1) AS NextClick,
       (SELECT clicks 
        FROM clicksTable 
        ORDER BY clicks DESC 
        LIMIT 1) AS TopClick;
```

Comment: This only returns one result

Comment: @PutraKg see my edit; that should return you what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But what if I want it to return an array instead of two value? something like in php $row['nextclick'] and $row['topclick']

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, I don't know php that well. If what you're asking for is a single row of data (rather than the two this would produce) then don't use the `UNION` and instead make these nested selects... SELECT * FROM (SELECT clicks.. ), (SELECT clicks...). But that is a different question

Comment: Simon, I've edited the question. It should not be about UNION in the first place. My apology.

Comment: @PutraKg check out my **Edit 2**

Comment: @Simon Martin, Hey Simon, your query is great in Edit 2, But is it possible to have return multiple rows , i mean i do not want LIMIT 1 in the sub queryies SELECT (SELECT clicks 
        FROM clicksTable 
        WHERE clicks > 199 
        ORDER BY clicks ASC 
        ) AS NextClick,

Comment: @SAM - short answer is no. Sounds like you're after a UNION. Think it's worth opening a new question to explore that though

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT clicks FROM
    (SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable WHERE clicks > 199 ORDER BY clicks ASC LIMIT 1) A
UNION
SELECT clicks FROM
    (SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 1) B;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, do you want a `union` or a `union all`?

The problem is the `order by` in the first part.  You can fix this, using subqueries:

```
(select * from (SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable WHERE clicks > 199 ORDER BY clicks ASC LIMIT 1))
UNION ALL
(select * from (SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 1))
```

In a `union` expression, `order by` is only allowed at the end and it applies to the entire expression.