# How to get record from a table with dynamic condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

i am having a table tb_user in which the records are as:

```
id   Name    Gender   Age
1    Arun     Male    23
2    Neha    Female   22
3   Sheetal  Female   21
4    Vikas    Male    20
```

what i need to do is if i get the id = 1 from the api then i need to to fetch the record which are apposite in gender.what i am doing is first fetching the gender of that id then putting the condition as follows:

```
Select Gender from tb_user where id = 1;
```

then another query to get the record for that id

```
Select * from tb_user where Gender != $gender;
```

$gender is the gender which we got from the previous query.

what is need to do is to complete this task in a single query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281663/combine-two-mysql-query-into-one maybe this can help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subQuery to achieve your goal.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE Gender <> (SELECT Gender FROM tb_user WHERE id = 1);
```